# `sklearn.manifold.LocallyLinearEmbedding` with custom neighbors search

Tags: scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I would like to implement a manifold alignment algorithm with `sklearn.manifold.LocallyLinearEmbedding` by using my custom way of defining neighbors, while the neighbors search is limited to `neighbors_algorithm{‘auto’, ‘brute’, ‘kd_tree’, ‘ball_tree’}, default=’auto’`. Should I subclass the original module to achieve that, or is it any quicker way?